# Does bias during hyperparameter tuning matter?

Tags: cross-validation, bias, hyperparameter

Different validation methods have different bias and variance. For instance, k-fold cross validation with high enough k (e.g. 10) has low bias, but high variance, whereas the bootstrap has lower variance but a high bias, comparable to the bias of 2-fold cross validation.

Please note that when I mention bias and variance, I mean the bias and variance of my estimation method (i.e. cv and bootstrap) and not the bias and variance of the model I am evaluating.

Suppose I am in the stage of hyperparameter optimisation, and I am tuning a single model. All I care about at the moment is to find out whether my model performs better with hyperparameter-set A or hyperparameter-set B. Does bias of my estimation method even matter in this situation? After all, I don't care that my estimations are off, as long as they are off the same for each comparison I make.

Is my thinking correct here?

If the answer is yes, should I favour bootstap over cv every time?

And if the answer is yes, how far does it hold? Does it hold as well for example when I adjust dropout in my model? When I add more augmented training data? Increase Layer size?

**Update**: While I am still interested in an answer, I am not so sure anymore whether it has any impact in practice. Specifically my initial remark that bootstrap has lower variance: For this to be relevant in practice, I'd have to compare methods with equal runtime, so under the assumption that only model fitting time is significant and that all compared methods use roughly equally-sized chunks of the training set, I'd need to compare 10-fold cv with 10 repetitions of the bootstrap, or 5-times repeated 10-fold cv with 50 repetitions of the bootstrap. Maybe in these cases, cross-validation always wins against the bootstrap.